# How and where can I modify the auto generated query from DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView and I wanted to update my table from the grid. I get the error "Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables" when using the DataAdapter.Update(dataTable). The reason is because I have filled my dataTable by joining 2 tables.

This is the function I am using to update my database from the grid.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.EndEdit();
        //da.Update(dataTable);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        com.Connection = connection;            
        com.CommandText = "update Name_Corpus2 set EngWord = @EngWord where ID = @ID";
        com.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 32, "ID");
        com.Parameters.Add("@EngWord", OleDbType.VarChar, 64, "EngWord");
        da.UpdateCommand = com;
        da.Update(dataTable);
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
        bind(classification, language);            
    }
```

I understand that I would have to create my own query for updating the table from the grid. I would like to know how and where would I have to enter the code to auto generate my update query.

Comment: You should create your own SqlCommand with its commandtext and parameters then set it as the UpdateCommand property of the DataAdapter

Comment: @Steve thanks for the fast response. So I did what you said and I am getting an error. Have updated my function in the question. When I try to update the table, it says "Must declare the scalar variable "@EngWord"."

Comment: Add the `@EngWord` parameter before the `@ID` (IE follow the exact order of the placeholders in the query. This is mandatory with OleDB)

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your help! I did as you said but I again faced a problem with the da.Update statement. So I got rid of the OleDB connection/commands and just used SqlConnection/SqlDataAdapter and it worked perfectly! Sorry if my questions were that of a rookie, this is my first windows form application!

Comment: When I was using the OleDB connection, I wasnt able to set the datatype for the @EngWord parameter to NVarChar because it seems like it only supports VarChar. Maybe thats what the issue was. After switching to SqlConnection I managed to change the datatype for the parameter to SqlDbType.NVarChar since in my SQL database, the EngWord column is of type nvarchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my updated function to auto generate the update query, by switching from OleDB commands to SqlCommand and adding the commandtext and parameters for it. Thank you @Steve

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.EndEdit();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.Parameters.Add("@EngWord", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256, "EngWord");
        com.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 32, "ID");
        com.CommandText = "update Name_Corpus2 set EngWord = @EngWord where ID = @ID";

        da.UpdateCommand = com;
        da.Update(dataTable);
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
        bind(classification, language);            
    }
```